# Image not displaying in HTML and Nodejs (404 Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to load an image into my html and I am running into issues when I run it with the nodejs. The image is not being found.

My folder set up:

|-- server.js
|-- Images/
|--white-knight-logo.gif
|-- JS
|-- Node_Modules
|-- Views
|--index.html

My server.js code looks like this:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var  mysql=require('mysql');
var path = require('path');



app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/JS'));
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);



app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index.html');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });



var server=app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("We have started our server on port 3000");
});
```

My html code looks like:

```
<body>
   <div class="page">
        <img src='white-knight-logo.gif'>
   </div>

    <div class="bs-example">
        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">

    </div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

This is the image I keep getting.  Please help.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/Heading.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start using nodeJS, you will need to have a proper structure of folders.
You need to have a folder called public inside your main project.
In public folder, create another folder and name it assets.
In assets folder, create another folder and name it images. Then, add all of your images in that images folder.

Remove

```
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
```

and add

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then, you can add your images path to html like this

```
<img src ="assets/images/nameofimage.jpg" ></img>

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I did exactly what you put and I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: I made some changes to the code. Try it now

Comment: Yeah I saw the error right after public/ and I added a '.  This still doesnt work.  Could it be because I using the server.js also for mysql connections.

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/JS')); app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');  What is these line for? Try removing them and see. I think they are not allowing  public to set up as default path

Comment: the JS file is a typeahead.min.js file for an autocomplete form function.  The views is where I have my index.html.

Comment: I took them off and it did not make a difference

Comment: So I created another folder and just added the code you provided and then ran the server and the image worked.  So it definitely is the other app.use I have.  How can I run both the images and the mysql